# I want to make a pop up menu that allows selection of different options on android

Tags: android, bitmap, drop-down-menu, slidingdrawer

I have a bitmap displaying some medical information and want to have an option to bring up a menu from the bottom of the bitmap which allows choosing different diagnostics, some within sub menus.

I had thought that possibly using a sliding draw would be a good simple idea for this but I think there must be a better way to do this. I must be able to have the options clickable so that the data can be saved to a file.

Any suggestions other than using a sliding draw and buttons would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the options menu of android. It can be set for each activity.

in the activity use the code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

}
```

And add a menu.xml file in the menu folder of the resources folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/export_menubutton_id" android:title="Export" />
    <item android:id="@+id/email_menubutton_id" android:title="Email" />
    <item android:id="@+id/facebook_menubutton_id" android:title="Facebook" />  
</menu>
```

Comment: is it limited to only 5 options in the menu or can you add more?

Comment: You can add upto 6. But if u you add more than that then a more button will be added which will show the remaining option.

Comment: I have created a list view and also a radio button selection option, when an item from the list is chosen the menu closes automatically however this doesn't happen with the radio button option. I can't seen anything that makes it close but i'm sure that there is, can you tell me how to make it happen?